# "Minus" not being captured

Tags: c

Running:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *exp = "10-2+3*5";
    char tok[255];
    sscanf(exp, "%[^+-*/^]", tok);
    printf("%s\n", tok);
    sscanf(exp, "%[^-+*/^]", tok);
    printf("%s\n", tok);
    return 0;
}
```

Would output:

```
10-2
10
```

But why?

Comment: Did you mean '/' for divide, by any chance (instead of '\' to escape the caret).

Comment: I'm guessing you can't escape it with the '\' which is why u need to put it at either end?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, that was a typo.
@Ashwin Yeah, it can't be escaped.

Comment: I just edited it. It was a silly question after all. Anyways, thanks for the help guys. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the hyphen at the end of your `[...]` set. This is similar to regular expressions.

sscanf's `%[...]` format accepts ranges. A range could be used like this: `%[a-z]`

In order to distinguish matching a plain hyphen, you must put it at the end, so it is not interpreted as a range.

You can find more documentation on the [sscanf manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sscanf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html). Scroll down to the section where the `[` pattern is described.

Comment: Yeah. It can't be escaped so either put it first or last. Thanks.